# Enabling or disabling a login view based on authentication state

Tags: java, android, authentication, comparative-review

Is it good to have this:

```
if(DataHolder.i().getLoginParamInfo().equals(LoginState.stateLoggingIn)) {
    getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button).setEnabled(true);
}
else {
    getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button).setEnabled(false);
}
```

or this:

```
getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button).setEnabled(DataHolder.i().getLoginParamInfo().equals(LoginState.stateLoggingIn));
```

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Code Review!  We don't usually handle philosophical questions like this.  You might get a better response from another site on the network.  Alternately, you could post a lot more code and ask for a [tag:comparative-review].  Incidentally, I don't like either of those options.  The first repeats itself unnecessarily while the second is overly dense.  With more context, I might be able to suggest more options, e.g. assigning to a temp variable.

Comment: In my opinion, the question is on-topic, since it looks like a plausible excerpt from a real program. However, it's a poorly posed question, since it lacks a lot of contextual information. I do see a lot of cause for concern, though, about the code quality in general. I encourage you to ask another question with more details about what you are trying to accomplish, along with a lot of the supporting code, so that we can provide a more thorough review.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short code vs longer code:

Writing shorter code can in certain situations be a good thing. But in your case I would not recommend this as it makes your code hard to read and/or maintain. Try something like this:

```
//I don't know the return-type of getLoginParamInfo(), hence the "LoginState".
LoginState parameterInfo = DataHolder.i().getLoginParamInfo();
boolean isLoggingIn = parameterInfo.equals(LoginState.stateLoggingIn);
getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button).setEnabled(isLoggingIn);
```

If you want, you can combine the first two lines into one. This gives following code:

```
boolean isEqual = DataHolder.i().getLoginParamInfo().equals(LoginState.stateLoggingIn);
getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button).setEnabled(isEqual);
```

But again, pumping al code in one line is certainly not a good practice.

## Method naming:

Giving your functions/methods names like `i()` is definitly not good practice. It doesn't tell anything about what it does and what it eventually returns.

Comment: I would rename `isEqual` to `isLoggingIn`. Then it becomes an explaining variable — and it also becomes Heslacher's answer.

Comment: @200_success Changed it, thanks for the useful tip! ;)

Answer (score 3):

**Neither**

You should declare a Boolean which will take the returned value of the `equals()` method and use it to call the `setEnabled()` method.

```
boolean isLoggedIn = DataHolder.i().getLoginParamInfo().equals(LoginState.stateLoggingIn);  
getView().findViewById(R.id.login_button).setEnabled(isLoggedIn);
```

Also this `i()` method looks really weird.

Comment: `i()` method is for instance. After my part of project finished, I'll replace it with the name `getInstance()` :)